# Maven compile error ProjectBuildingException

Tags: maven, build, compilation, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm trying to compile with maven a specific snapshot of Apache log4j.

I obtain this error:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin is missing. @ line 89, column 15
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin].dependencies.dependency.scope' for junit:junit:jar must be one of [compile, runtime, system] but is 'test'. @ line 321, column 20

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:416)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:663)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:654)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:243)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]   The project log4j:log4j:1.2.17-SNAPSHOT (/scratch/test/log4j/code/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin].dependencies.dependency.scope' for junit:junit:jar must be one of [compile, runtime, system] but is 'test'. @ line 321, column 20
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

This is the POM file:

```
    <!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.

-->
<!--
Usage notes:

To build NTEventLogAppender.dll using MinGW, place mingw\bin on path for Windows or install mingw
package on other platforms.  Build will execute gcc and windres on Windows and
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc and i586-mingw32msvc-windres on other platforms.

To build NTEventLogAppender.dll using Microsoft tools, run the appropriate vcvars for the
target platform and specify -Dntdll_target=msbuild on the mvn command line.

-->        
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Apache Log4j</name>
  <version>1.2.17-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Apache Log4j 1.2</description>
  <url>http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/</url>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>Bugzilla</system>
    <url>http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/</url>
  </issueManagement>
  <ciManagement>
    <system>Gump</system>
    <url>http://vmgump.apache.org/gump/public/logging-log4j-12/logging-log4j-12/index.html</url>
  </ciManagement>
  <inceptionYear>1999</inceptionYear>
  <mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
      <name>log4j-user</name>
      <subscribe>log4j-user-subscribe@logging.apache.org</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>log4j-user-unsubscribe@logging.apache.org</unsubscribe>
      <post>log4j-user@logging.apache.org</post>
      <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/</archive>
      <otherArchives>
        <otherArchive>http://marc.info/?l=log4j-user</otherArchive>
        <otherArchive>http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.log4j.user</otherArchive>
      </otherArchives>
    </mailingList>
    <mailingList>
      <name>log4j-dev</name>
      <subscribe>log4j-dev-subscribe@logging.apache.org</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>log4j-dev-unsubscribe@logging.apache.org</unsubscribe>
      <post>log4j-dev@logging.apache.org</post>
      <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-dev/</archive>
      <otherArchives>
        <otherArchive>http://marc.info/?l=log4j-dev</otherArchive>
        <otherArchive>http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.log4j.devel</otherArchive>
      </otherArchives>
    </mailingList>
  </mailingLists>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk</url>
  </scm>
  <organization>
    <name>Apache Software Foundation</name>
    <url>http://www.apache.org</url>
  </organization>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>tests</workingDirectory>
          <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
          <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
          <skip>true</skip>
          <includes>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/LevelTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/PriorityTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/CategoryTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/FileAppenderTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/LogManagerTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/helpers.LogLogTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/LayoutTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/helpers.DateLayoutTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/TTCCLayoutTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/xml.XMLLayoutTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayoutTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/spi.LoggingEventTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/spi.ThrowableInformationTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/spi.LocationInfoTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfiguratorTest.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/MinimumTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/LoggerTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/PatternLayoutTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/HierarchyThresholdTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/xml/CustomLevelTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/customLogger/XLoggerTestCase.java</include>
            <!-- DefaultInit  -->
            <!-- SocketServer -->
            <include>org/apache/log4j/xml/XMLLayoutTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/xml/AsyncAppenderTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilterTestCase.java</include>
            <!--   ErrorHandlerTestCase is not run in Ant build either
           <include>org/apache/log4j/varia/ErrorHandlerTestCase.java</include>
           -->
            <!-- include>org/apache/log4j/helpers/OptionConverterTestCase.java</include -->
            <include>org/apache/log4j/helpers/BoundedFIFOTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/helpers/CyclicBufferTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/helpers/PatternParserTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/or/ORTestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/DRFATestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/RFATestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/varia/ERFATestCase.java</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppenderTest</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppenderTest</include>
            <include>org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppenderTest</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.1</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestSections>
              <manifestSection>
                <name>org.apache.log4j</name>
                <manifestEntries>
                  <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                  <Implementation-Title>log4j</Implementation-Title>
                  <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                  <Implementation-Vendor>"Apache Software Foundation"</Implementation-Vendor>
                </manifestEntries>
              </manifestSection>
            </manifestSections>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <!--   generate NTEventLogAppender.dll    -->
          <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <id>ntdll</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <ant antfile="src/ntdll/build.xml" target="${ntdll_target}">
                  <property name="target.dir" location="target" />
                  <property name="classes.dir" location="target/classes" />
                  <property name="src.dir" location="src/ntdll" />
                  <property name="jni.include.dir" location="${java.home}/../include" />
                </ant>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!--   create tests/output prior to test run    -->
          <execution>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <id>mkdir_tests_output</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <mkdir dir="tests/output" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <id>rmdir_tests_output</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <delete dir="tests/output" />
                <delete dir="tests/classes" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <id>runAll</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                 <ant dir="tests" target="runAll">
                  <property name="m2_repo" location="${m2_repo}" />
                  <property name="log4j.jar" location="target/classes" />
                  <property name="project.lib.home" location="target" />
                </ant>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!--   release builds will put SVN tags into the SCM page, this changes it back to trunk  -->
          <execution>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <id>untag-site</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <taskdef name="replaceregexp" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp" />
                <replaceregexp file="target/site/source-repository.html" match="/tags/[^ &quot;'&lt;]*" replace="/trunk" flags="g" />
                <replaceregexp match="-- Generated by (.*) on .*--" replace="-- Generated by \1 --" flags="g">
                  <fileset dir="target/site/apidocs" includes="**/*.html" />
                </replaceregexp>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>post-site</phase>
            <id>post-site</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <ant target="post-site" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <id>site-deploy</id>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <ant target="site-deploy" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>javadoc.resources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/apidocs/META-INF">
                  <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                    <include name="LICENSE" />
                    <include name="NOTICE" />
                  </fileset>
                </copy>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${tools.jar}</systemPath>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>assembly</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>

      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
          <excludedocfilessubdir>.svn</excludedocfilessubdir>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <docEncoding>UTF-8</docEncoding>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
              <goal>javadoc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>site</id>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>javadoc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
        <!--
         Bug MRELEASE-273 has been throwing NPE during release:perform,
         typically after deploy so this places it last.
       -->
        <configuration>
          <goals>package site-deploy assembly:attached deploy</goals>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!--
       clirr:check will fail with NullPointerException
       due to missing javax.jms.MessageListener,
       however it will trigger download of supporting components
       which can allow "ant clirr" to succeed.
       Could possibly run on a JavaEE platform.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <comparisonVersion>1.2.15</comparisonVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>tests/witness/**</exclude>
                <exclude>tests/output/**</exclude>
                <exclude>tests/classes/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <!-- omit chainsaw and LF5   -->
                <Export-Package>!org.apache.log4j.lf5.*,
                                !org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.*,
                                org.apache.log4j.*;version=1.2.17;-noimport:=true</Export-Package>
                <!--  all other potential imports are covered by DynamicImport-Package earlier -->
                <Import-Package>!javax.swing.*,
                                !com.ibm.uvm.tools.*,
                                !com.sun.jdmk.comm.*,
                                javax.jmdns.*;resolution:=optional,
                                javax.jms.*;resolution:=optional,
                                javax.mail.*;resolution:=optional,
                                *</Import-Package>
                <Bundle-DocURL>http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2</Bundle-DocURL>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testSourceDirectory>tests/src/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>tests/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>mac</id>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <family>mac</family>
        </os>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <tools.jar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</tools.jar>
        <m2_repo>${user.home}/.m2/repository</m2_repo>
        <ntdll_target>build</ntdll_target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <tools.jar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</tools.jar>
        <m2_repo>${user.home}/.m2/repository</m2_repo>
        <ntdll_target>build</ntdll_target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0-2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--  the following dependency is not needed on JDK 1.5 and higher
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1</version>
     <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
   -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>oro</groupId>
      <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
  <reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>scm</report>
              <report>dependencies</report>
              <report>cim</report>
              <report>issue-tracking</report>
              <report>mailing-list</report>
              <report>license</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>changes-report</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
        <configuration>
          <issueLinkTemplate>%URL%/show_bug.cgi?id=%ISSUE%</issueLinkTemplate>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>logging.repo</id>
      <url>scp://people.apache.org/www/people.apache.org/builds/logging/repo/</url>
    </repository>
    <site>
      <id>logging.site</id>
      <url>scp://localhost/${user.dir}/target/site-deploy</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

What do you think is the cause of the problem? Is the pom file malformed? Are there some unresolved dependencies?

I'm using Apache Maven 3.0.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The log4j version you are running was designed with maven2.

Try to run it with maven2.

Answer (score 1):

Scope parameter for junit dependency can only have values - compile, runtime, system.

This indicates to Maven that the dependency will be provided at runtime/compile/system by its container or JDK.

Try removing scope or give valid value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

But why do you think the Apache developers used that scope? Should it be defined in the pom.xml? The error is because the <scope>test</scope> is called but not defined? Or simply the junit cannot accept any other scope??

Thanks!!

Comment: It usually works fine with scope as 'test' for junit. I could not think of possible solution than removing the scope. And another thing i noticed in your pom file is that junit was defined twice for 2 different versions. You should understand it takes the 1st declaration closest to your project.